# Append string on grep multiple results with variable in a single command

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, grep

The filename contain space, e.g. `example like this.txt` and I want to append `"` on the prefix and postfix of that string. e.g. `"example like this.txt"`.

Moreover, I also want to append the number on every line from the grep result

For example, this command will return several lines:

```
ls -a | grep "filename"
```

For example:

```
example filename a.txt
example filename b.txt
example filename c.txt
example filename d.txt
```

How can I append multiple strings on each return line using a single command? So that I get this output:

```
1 "example filename a.txt"
2 "example filename b.txt"
3 "example filename c.txt"
4 "example filename d.txt"
```

Comment: Where are these numbers supposed to come from in your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a single command you will need to go with something like `awk`, `perl` or `python`:

For example:

```
$ ls -la | awk '/filename/{printf "%s %s%s%s\n",++i,q,$0,q}' q='"' 
1 "example filename a.txt"
2 "example filename b.txt"
3 "example filename c.txt"
4 "example filename d.txt"
```