# Add grep results to array or list as separate entries

Tags: arrays, shell, variables, grep

I have a similar issue to these cases:

[Set a grep result into multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708197/set-a-grep-result-into-multiple-variables)

[Append string on grep multiple results with variable in a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947813/append-string-on-grep-multiple-results-with-variable-in-a-single-command)

But I cannot take their solutions and adapt them sufficiently

I have a query that returns a list of URLs, the URLs are uniformly formatted and each URL contains a 3 digit number on the end

I have copied an example into a file

```
"url": "https://dev.azure.com/example/5121186b-6db9-49f7-8fcd-64e88a5c606d/_apis/build/Builds/238",
"url": "https://dev.azure.com/example/5121186b-6db9-49f7-8fcd-64e88a5c606d/_apis/build/Builds/239",
"url": "https://dev.azure.com/example/5121186b-6db9-49f7-8fcd-64e88a5c606d/_apis/build/Builds/240",
"url": "https://dev.azure.com/example/5121186b-6db9-49f7-8fcd-64e88a5c606d/_apis/build/Builds/241",
```

I am trying to grab the 3 digit build number on the end of each URL

This works using this from the command line

```
(grep _apis/build/Builds build.txt | cut -d "/" -f9 | grep -Eo '[0-9]*')

238
239
240
241
```

However, if I try to capture each value into a variable array (list?) that I can loop over later, it goes wrong

```
queued_builds="$(grep _apis/build/Builds build.txt | cut -d "/" -f9 | grep -Eo '[0-9]*')"
```

If I print the entire $queued_builds array it looks ok?

```
echo "${queued_builds[@]}"
238
239
240
241
```

But if I print out $queued_builds, it looks like they are all being added as a single item/string with newline characters between them?

```
printf '%q\n' "$queued_builds[@]"

238$'\n'239$'\n'240$'\n'241
```

If I try to access a specific row/entry, I get individual characters from each string rather than an entire string?

```
echo $queued_builds[1]
2

echo $queued_builds[2]
3

echo $queued_builds[3]
8

etc.
```

I am trying to have each result/line as a var entry, so

```
echo $queued_builds[1]
238

echo $queued_builds[2]
239

echo $queued_builds[3]
240

etc.
```

I need this as I later want to loop over each build ID using something like:

```
for build in ${queued_builds[@]}; do echo "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/build/builds/$build?api-version=7.0"; done
```

Do I need to do something specific with my variable result assignment to make each result a new array item (or list item, array vs list is also still a little muddy at this point)?

Many thanks

Comment: Does is work if you remove the `"`'s? `queued_builds=$(grep _apis/build/Builds build.txt | cut -d "/" -f9 | grep -Eo '[0-9]*')`

Comment: `queued_builds=($(grep _apis/build/Builds build.txt | cut -d "/" -f9 | grep -Eo '[0-9]*'))` gives 4 with `echo ${#queued_builds[@]}` in bash for the example above

Comment: btw, if input contains json data, better to extract url values with jq and then split each that value into array with IFS=/ (anyway you use some shell with array support), and then use/print the last element of those arrays

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using SED :

```
declare -a queued_builds

queued_builds=( $(sed -e '/_apis\/build\/Builds/!d' -e 's/^.\+\/\([0-9]\{3\}\)",$/\1/' build.txt) )

length="${#queued_builds[@]}"

echo "there are $length elements in queued_builds"

for ((i = 0; i < $length; ++i ))                                                                                                                                                               
do echo "element $i: ${queued_builds[$i]}"
done
```

Output:

```
there are 4 elements in queued_builds
element 0: 238
element 1: 239
element 2: 240
element 3: 241
```

Hope that helps.